# latex writes summation symbols in fractions, and the superscripts and subscripts of the summation symbols are misplaced

Tags: equations

I'm trying to use the summation symbol in fractions, but I found that the superscript and subscript of the summation symbol go to the side, is this allowed mathematically? Or am I writing the Latex code wrong?

```latex
$$
    \begin{aligned}
        w = \frac{
            \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 0}^{m} (-2x_1y_1)
        }{
            2\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 0}^{m} x_1^2
        }
    \end{aligned}
$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is allowed in maths. This is the inline mode which can be inserted in text if with only the denominator for example.

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    w = \frac{
        \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 0}^{m} (-2x_1y_1)
    }{
        2\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 0}^{m} x_1^2
    }
\]

\[
    w = \frac{
        \frac{1}{m} \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m} (-2x_1y_1)
    }{
        2\frac{1}{m} \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m} x_1^2
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: Result]

Adding `\limits` after the `\sum` does the trick.

> By the way, [`\[ \]` is preferrable to `$$ $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: @hair-splitter Oops indeed and I will make an edit. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any difference between [...] and $$...$$ ? They seem to produce similar results.

Comment: @aszswaz Please follow the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for details. In brief, it is more robust.